# d3 v4 - uneven grid spaces in date axis

Tags: d3.js

I have trouble with "date" axis, to set it to equal spaces. 
When month ends on uneven number (31 days) grid resets itself to start from first of month.

As far as I understand it is default d3 behavior, it can be seen on other chart out there at bl.ocks.

[image]

Working demo of the issue:
https://bl.ocks.org/bfunc/9640511725a77d677d4ed2405d2832e3